# CASE Statement inside CHECK Constraint Error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, constraints

I am trying to use a `CASE` statement inside a `CHECK` constraint in SQL Server, but I get this error:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

```
create table dbo.Advertisement
(
    advertisement_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    roadside_bottom varchar (20),
    roadside_top_bottom varchar (20),
    curbside varchar (20),
    rearside varchar (20),
    headliner varchar(10),
    bus varchar (10),
    CONSTRAINT bottom_pass 
        CHECK(CASE 
                  WHEN roadside_bottom = 'King' AND roadside_top_bottom IS NULL THEN 1 
                  WHEN roadside_bottom = 'Super King' and roadside_top_bottom IS NULL THEN 1 
              END)  
);
```

I need help with the syntax for.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: Kinda weird to enforce that a column must always be null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case`, but it returns a value and that needs to be compares to something:

```
CONSTRAINT bottom_pass CHECK
(
    CASE WHEN roadside_bottom = 'King' AND roadside_top_bottom IS NULL THEN 1 
         WHEN roadside_bottom = 'Super King' and roadside_top_bottom IS NULL THEN 1
    END = 1
)
```

However, this would more concisely be written as:

```
CONSTRAINT bottom_pass CHECK
(
    roadside_top_bottom IS NULL AND
    roadside_bottom IN ('King', 'Super King')
)
```